# Angular Material inline calendar picker 'selected' property binding not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I'm using property & event binding to `selected` attribute in angular material calendar like in docs:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-calendar [(selected)]="selected"></mat-calendar>
</mat-card>
<code>{{ selected }}</code>

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  selected = new Date(1999, 1, 1);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selected = new Date(1999, 2, 2);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.selected = new Date(1999, 3, 3);
  }
}
```

The problem is calendar is not adjusting it's view to the set date.
[image: result]

[Stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6lxsp3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is the usage of `[startAt]` input.

When we want to start the calendar with the default value we need to pass it as startAt.

So in your case, you can make a fast check by adding

`<mat-calendar [(selected)]="selected" [startAt]="selected"></mat-calendar>`

Those should be separate variables so change them after checkup if this work for you.

Comment: That helped a bit, view changes to the correct month, however the selected date is not selected https://angular-ivy-6lxsp3.stackblitz.io

Comment: figured that out. selected binding did not work when used in AfterViewInit. In OnInit it works like charm. Case solved